# Problem with special characters in regexp using preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, regex-negation

i have problem with regexp which is trying to find if phrase I search is within a `<hx>` tag or not

this is the example:
https://regex101.com/r/xAlJJc/3

as you can see there's exactly 1 match in example, this is fine

the problem is that the moment you add a dot, comma or other character to this `<h1>test string</h1>` regexp is going crazy and show 2 matches

does anyone knows how to make sure that this:
https://regex101.com/r/xAlJJc/4

will not find any matches for "test string"?

Comment: `regexp is going crazy`, not really, the regex is only doing what's it's told to do :D

Comment: To be honest, the approach is crap - use a parser instead, `PHP` has plenty. If you insist: which tags do you want to ignore?

Comment: Are you looking for sth. like this: https://regex101.com/r/xAlJJc/5 ?

Comment: Hey @Jan - the idea is to parse any matched word and change to URL, words insode HTML coded description, sometimes tho i'd like to skip words which are inside of <hx> tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case the solution was to use this regex:

`(Test)(?![^>]*?[^<]*?<\/a>)(?![^>]*?[^<]*?<\/button>)(?![^>]*?[^<]*?<\/h[1-6]>)`

thank you for your efforts guys :)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you may want to give this a try:

`^<\w*>(test string)<\/\w*>`